# Insertion Sort using string.compareTo()

Tags: java

As far as I can tell, I have implemented the basic insertion sort here. The output is the same array, unsorted. Am I making use of compareTo correctly? I am unsure what it means by being some number greater than or less than zero.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int lineNumber = 5;
    int i,j;
    String key;
    String[] inputArray = {"E","D","C","B","A","B"};
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(inputArray));
    for (j = 1; j < lineNumber; j++) {
        key = inputArray[j];
        i = j - 1;
        while (i >= 0) {
            if (key.compareTo(inputArray[i]) < 0) {
                break;
            }
            inputArray[i + 1] = inputArray[i];
            i--;
        }
        inputArray[i + 1] = key;
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(inputArray));
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(inputArray));
}
```

run:

```
[E, D, C, B, A, B]

[E, D, C, B, A, B]

[E, D, C, B, A, B]

[E, D, C, B, A, B]

[E, D, C, B, A, B]

[E, D, C, B, A, B]

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: Why is the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String)) not sufficient for you? - "*Returns : the value 0 if the argument string is equal to this string; a value less than 0 if this string is lexicographically less than the string argument; and a value greater than 0 if this string is lexicographically greater than the string argument.*"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out: no, you are not making correct use of `compareTo()`. The below code works as intended.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int i,j;
  String key;
  String[] inputArray = {"E","D","C","B","A","B"};
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(inputArray));
  for (j = 1; j < inputArray.length; j++) { //the condition has changed
    key = inputArray[j];
    i = j - 1;
    while (i >= 0) {
      if (key.compareTo(inputArray[i]) > 0) {//here too
        break;
      }
      inputArray[i + 1] = inputArray[i];
      i--;
    }
    inputArray[i + 1] = key;
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(inputArray));
  }
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(inputArray));
}
```

Why the `compareTo()` does what it does is explained very well in the other answers. Besides that i changed until what value the for-loop should run, it should run until the end of the array (array.length), not until any other number.

Comment: This is correct.  Might be helpful to explain the reason for each of those changes though.

Comment: enough explanation - or should i do more, both are quite minor changes!?

Comment: @luk2302: OP is confused about returned number after using `compareTo()` which detailed in [`public int compareTo(String anotherString)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String)). That means why `-1 OR 1 OR 0` ?

Comment: @Smit i know - what compareTo returns is covered in the answer by Alex well enough, istn´t it?

Answer (score 3):

This implementation is almost correct, but there are a couple of issues:

- By checking `key.compareTo(inputArray[i]) < 0`, you're sorting in descending order. If this condition is true, then it means that `key` is lexicographally before `inputArray[i]`, and by using that as your terminating condition on the inner loop, you're ensuring that `key` is inserted such that everything before it is greater, and everything after is less. Change this to `key.compareTo(inputArray[i]) >= 0` to sort in ascending order.
- You have `lineNumber = 5` but there are 6 items in the array. Change this to 6 (or better yet, use `inputArray.length`.

So, you were sorting the first 5 array entries in reverse order, and since the first 5 items in your input array happened to already be in reverse order, you saw no change. This is why it's a good idea to test your code with a variety of inputs :-)

Answer (score 1):

found on: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo(T)

int compareTo(T o)
Compares this object with the specified object for order. Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
if(key.compareTo(inputArray[i]) < 0)
```

is incorrect, you need to switch the '<' sign to a '>' and it will sort it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only comparing the characters A, B, C, D,... , then why not compare the characters instead? Then you could do `theChar <= 'A'` or something along those lines.