# Java String Insertion Sort Not Working As Desired

Tags: java, insertion-sort

My objective is to create a working insertion sort that can handle strings and integers using the array given to us in the main method. For this example I called it list.

```
public class insort{

public static void main(String[]list){
  sort(list);
  printsort(list);
}//main

public static void sort(String[]list){
  for (int index = 1; index < list.length; index++){
    int key = list[index];
    int position = index;
    while (position > 0 && key.compareTo(list[position-1]) < 0){
        list[position] = list[position-1];
        position--;
    }//while
  list[position] = key;
 }//for
}//sort

public static void printsort(String[]list){
  while ( i < list.length){
    System.out.print(i);
  }//while
 }//printsort
}//insort
```

Comment: and what do you have problems with? what's the output of your code?

Comment: @eis hi, unfortunately, I am unable to complie the code as I am comparing strings to integers. I am unsure how to continue.

Comment: `int key = list[index];` // This will return a String. Not an int. Compiler will show the error.

Comment: Perhaps the duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17432738/insertion-sort-using-string-compareto

Comment: @ThanigaiArasu I appreciate your comments and link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the things to note for successful compilation:

1. The 'i' in the 'printsort' method is not declared and initialized. You will need to something like `int i=0` before you start the while loop.
2. Also the while loop variable needs to be updated inside the loop so as to meet an end condition. The end condition will help you stop the loop from going into an infinite loop. So you will need an `i++` after your System.out.print().
3. In the System.out.print() you are passing the variable `i` which will print the numbers from 0 to length-1 instead of the Strings in your list array. So you will need something like `System.out.print(list[i])`.
4. In the 'sort' method you have `int key = list[index]`, the RHS will return a String object instead of an int that you have on the LHS. `So String key = list[index]` is what you need there.

I haven't checked the code for proper working of insertion sort. Just pointed out some syntactic mistakes that will help you compile the code.

All the best :)

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate this.

Answer (score 0):

You mixed couple things. It would be much easier to sort `int` or `Integer` objects, than `String` objects (especially that you need to be sure that `String[] list` contains only numerics), however if you want to sort String objects you need to change couple things:

1. you try to assign a reference to `String` object to primitive variable
   `int`:

   ```
   int key = list[index];
   ```

   You can change it for example to:

   ```
   int key = Integer.valueOf(list[index]);
   ```

   or change list from `String[]` to `int[]`.
2. you try to use `compareTo()` method on primitive variable `int`:

   ```
   int key = list[index];
   (key.compareTo(list[position-1])) < 0
   ```

   Primitive variables doesn't have methods. You can solve the 1 and 2
   problems with usage of `Integer` object instead of `int` variable:

   ```
   Integer key = Integer.valueOf(list[index]);
   ```

   or, if you want to stay with `int` variables, try with:

   ```
   key < list[position-1]
   ```

   instead of:

   ```
   (key.compareTo(list[position-1])) < 0
   ```
3. your `while` loop is wrong:

   ```
   while ( i < list.length){
       System.out.print(i);
   }//while
   ```

   try with:

   ```
   for(String element : list){
       System.out.println(element);
   }
   ```

   to print every element of `list`.

also you changed a `main` method, from `main(String[] args)` to `main(String[] list)`, and you try to use sort on `String[] list`. You should create new `String[]` array, and try with it, for example:

```
String[] list = {"4","6","1","8"};
sort(list);
```

Comment: Thank you. This helped me understand sorting much better.